# Create parent folder and subfolders?

Tags: macos, bash

At the Bash prompt, I typed:

```
mkdir -p string_extend/{lib, pkg, test, doc, bin}
```

This creates folders that are separate from each other, which is not what I want.

I would like the parent to be `string_extend` and there to be five sub-folders inside of it, i.e., `lib`, `pkg`, `test`, etc. What is the correct line of code to achieve this?

Setup: Mac OSX version 10.8 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3):

Bash brace expansions need to be separated by commas only. Try this instead:

```
mkdir -p string_extend/{lib,pkg,test,doc,bin}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for ruby code, you could do:

```
require 'fileutils'
dirs = %w(lib pkg test doc bin)
dirs.each do |dir| FileUtils.mkdir_p("string_extend/#{dir}") end
```